# Hover after CSS animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to have a hover work after a css animation.
The animation changes size and colour of a circle using keyframes, however after the animation is complete, the colour it finishes on will not change on hover as it normally would.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

#panorama {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 4vw;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#panorama.large {
  width: 17vw;
  height: 17vw;
}

#panorama.black {
  background-color: black;
  border: solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 1px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6));
  -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6));
}

#panorama.glow {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#panorama.large.black.glow {
  animation-name: panoramaLargeBlackGlowDownTurnOn;
}

@keyframes panoramaLargeBlackGlowDownTurnOn {
  0% {
    width: 17vw;
    height: 17vw;
    background-color: black;
  }
  99% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    width: 3.5vw;
    height: 3.5vw;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
    -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
  }
}

#panorama.large.black.glow:hover {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div id="panorama" class="large black glow"></div>
</a>
```

or see the code here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JUST_ROB/d28ny3jg/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using `forwards` which will force the use of the last state of your animation and you cannot override it. To overcome this you can consider CSS variable to define the background coloration and you simply change the variable to change the background

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

#panorama {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 4vw;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#panorama.large {
  width: 17vw;
  height: 17vw;
}

#panorama.black {
  background-color: black;
  border: solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 1px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6));
}

#panorama.glow {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#panorama.large.black.glow {
  animation-name: panoramaLargeBlackGlowDownTurnOn;
}

@keyframes panoramaLargeBlackGlowDownTurnOn {
  0% {
    width: 17vw;
    height: 17vw;
    background-color: black;
  }
  99% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    width: 3.5vw;
    height: 3.5vw;
    background-color: var(--c,#fff);
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
  }
}

#panorama.large.black.glow:hover {
  --c: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div id="panorama" class="large black glow"></div>
</a>
```

Another idea is to use an inset box-shadow for the coloration:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

#panorama {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 4vw;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#panorama.large {
  width: 17vw;
  height: 17vw;
}

#panorama.black {
  background-color: black;
  border: solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 1px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6));
}

#panorama.glow {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#panorama.large.black.glow {
  animation-name: panoramaLargeBlackGlowDownTurnOn;
}

@keyframes panoramaLargeBlackGlowDownTurnOn {
  99% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    width: 3.5vw;
    height: 3.5vw;
    background-color: #fff;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
  }
}

#panorama.large.black.glow:hover {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 50vw red inset;
  border-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6); /*we also change the border since background is also visible under the border*/
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div id="panorama" class="large black glow"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: @RJM on mobile we don't have hover .. ?

Comment: yes, although with when you click on mobile it would normally show the hover state right? Perhaps it can also be hover, active, focus for mobile? but that doesnt seem to do it. Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: @RJM you are testing with what? did you clear cache?

Comment: yes, i have it set with hover, active, focus. I just cleared the cache although no luck there. It acts as if there is no hover, active or focus event to change the colour

Comment: @RJM probably CSS variable aren't supported in mobile .. but It seems yes https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables ... will add another way without CSS variable

Comment: Genius! thats it! :-)